# APEX Classic Report (based on Function) doesn't work

Tags: oracle, report, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

APEX 5 - I have a Classic Report (based on Function) from the following statement:

```
declare 
    bamsan varchar(3000);
begin
    if v('foo')= 'lansan' then
        bamsan := 'select id, cpu_cores, cpu_model, disk_gb from physical_servers where PHYSICALSERVERID like (select LEFTPHYSICALDEVICEID from SAN_PHYS_CON where CONNECTIONID like :meklet_value)';
    elsif v('foo')= 'storage' then 
        bamsan := 'select id, modelis, customerstoragename from storages where storageid like :meklet_value';
    elsif v('foo')= 'clusters' then 
        bamsan := 'select id, memberhostid from clusters_pools where clusterpoolid = :meklet_value';
    elsif v('foo')= 'hostname' then 
        bamsan := 'select id, cpu_cores, cpu_model, disk_gb from physical_servers where PHYSICALSERVERID like (select parentid from hosts where hostname like :meklet_value)';
    else 
        bamsan := 'select id, cpu_cores, cpu_model, disk_gb from physical_servers where PHYSICALSERVERID like :meklet_value';
    end if;
    return bamsan;
end;
```

The choice `elsif v('foo')= 'clusters'...` brings up the error:

> ORA-20001: Error fetching column value: ORA-01403: no data found

I'm 100% sure that the table and the columns exist (I can run this select from SQLDeveloper and Apex SQL Commands). Is this really an APEX bug or am I missing something?

Comment: The error message means that the query returns no rows.

Comment: But why doesn't it display my customized no data message?

Comment: It's not the query that's raising no_data_found: notice that it's actually `ORA-20001: Error fetching column value` - this is raised by Apex after getting the results of the query - I suspect you have a LOV-type column in the report definition that fails to find the value for one or more rows returned by that query.

Comment: Could this have something to do with the different number of columns you select? How many columns are displayed in the Page Designer?

Answer (score 1):

in this case the problem is your dinamic query because in some selects are different number of columns...
yo could select the option "Use Generic Column Names"